# Text box in between previous and next button to navigate into table

Tags: jquery

Following code is for table pagination it is working fine.My doubt is when I want to move 10th record directly each time i don't want to click next button,Instead of that I added text box if I enter 10 in text box direct it should show 10th page .Like that last and first buttons it should display last and first page of table.
https://jsfiddle.net/6aqytrkw/
Is it possible to do?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
                var table =  $('#myTable');
                var max_size=userDetails.length;
                var sta = 0;
                var j=1;
                var elements_per_page = 3;
                var limit = elements_per_page;
                 $('.paginationList').append('<input type="text" class="btn col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12">');
                 $('.paginationList input').val(1);
                pagination(sta,limit);

                function pagination(sta,limit){
                console.log(sta,limit);
                    for(var i=sta;i<limit;i++){
                    var tab='<tr id="row'+i+'"><td>'+userDetails[i].Sno+"\n"+'</td><td>'+userDetails[i].empId+"\n"+'</td><td>'+userDetails[i].Firstname+"\n"+'</td><td>'+userDetails[i].email+"\n"+'</td><td>'
                              +userDetails[i].phone+"\n"+'</td><td>'+userDetails[i].designation+"\n"+'</td><td>'+userDetails[i].projectAllocated+"\n"+'</td><td><button class="btn btn-info btn-xs edit" data-toggle="modal"  data-target="#myModal" data-html="true">'+
                              userDetails[i].edit +'</button><button class="btn btn-warning  btn-xs dlt">'+userDetails[i].remove +'</button></td></tr>';

                     $('#myTable').append(tab)
                }
                }
                $('#nextValue').click(function(){
                    var next = limit;
                    if(max_size>=next) {
                    j= eval(j+1);
                    def = limit+elements_per_page;
                    limit = def
                    table.empty();
                    if(limit > max_size) {
                    def = max_size;
                    }
                    $('.paginationList input').val(j);
                        pagination(next,def);
                    }
                });
                  $('#PreValue').click(function(){
                    var pre = limit-(2*elements_per_page);
                    if(pre>=0) {
                    j = eval(j-1);
                    limit = limit-elements_per_page;
                    table.empty();
                    $('.paginationList input').val(j);
                    pagination(pre,limit); 
                    }
                });


});
```

Comment: You'd normally want a button to action the jump to page, rather than "enter 10 in text box" - there needs to be a trigger, what if the user wanted to enter "100"?  You could do onblur, but users are used to typing a value and clicking something.  So add a jump-to button and trigger on that.  Otherwise, it's not clear what the problem is as you've provided what you currently have and just a "wish list".

Comment: @ freedomn-m OK. I can use buttons right?If I have 20 pages means I can display only 4 buttons when I click next on that time I can show rest of all buttons right?

Comment: Extend your original suggestion: [previous btn] [page input] [jump to page btn] [next btn], so example html : `<button>prev</button><input type='text'><button>go</button><button>next</button>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By adding the following code I got expected answer
html:

```
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-xs-12">

        <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-2 col-xs-12 padding pull-right">
        <button class="col-lg-11 col-xs-12 bgColor" id="nextValue">Next</button>
        </div>  
        <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-2 col-xs-12 padding pull-right">
        <button class="col-lg-11 col-xs-12 bgColor" id="go">Go</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-2 col-xs-12 paginationList padding pull-right">
        </div>
         <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-2 col-xs-12 padding pull-right">
        <button class="col-lg-11 col-xs-12 bgColor" id="PreValue">Pre</button>
        </div>

    </div>
```

script:

```
$('#go').click(function(){
                   var displayPage=$('#pageNo').val();
                   j=displayPage;
                   var ending_row=displayPage*elements_per_page;
                   var starting_row=ending_row-elements_per_page;
                   table.empty();
                   {
                    $('.paginationList input').val(j);
                        pagination(starting_row,ending_row);
                    }
                 });
```

Comment: @ freedomn-m Thanks for giving idea.